# Response data sending in back ground

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have an iPad application in which I need to send some datas to the server and if get success response the data is deleted from my cache folder . I am currently using asihttp network queue  to do this and working fine in one viewcontroller . But what actually i want is to process the sending with in the application through out not in a single viewcontroller and process response. Currently when i move to next view controller i need to stop the networkqueue. Is there any way to do this as a backgrond thread, any samples may greatly appreciated.

Comment: PLease be aware that `ASIHTTP` is not longer supported and has some bugs. if possible you should switch to an other framework like `AFNetworking`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to move to a more updated framework as ASIHTTP is no longer supported. I suggest you look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for this purpose. This framework allows you to perform your requests using NSOperation subclasses like AFJSONRequestOperation. NSOperations can be cancelled. Be aware that the cancellation of an NSOperation object may not happen immediately if it has started already. Moreover, for better performance, best practice and a bunch of other really good reasons, you should use an NSOperationQueue object to manage your requests. AFNetworking provides a convenience queue for you to use (suggested), but you can also create one of your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSURLConnection, in conjunction with GCD Blocks to run the process in a separate thread.

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("attendanceLoader", nil);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
     //YOUR NETWORK CALL HERE
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       //AFTER NETWORK CALL IS COMPLETE
       //DELETE CACHE HERE

    });

});//end of GCD
```